# How do I make my OnTap to move to a new screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, gesturedetector, flutter-card

This is part of my code, when I tap it does not move to MathYear() page

```
GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MathYear() ),
                  );
                },
                child: Card(
                  color: Color(0xffb0dab9),
                  elevation: 5,
                  child: Row(
                      children:<Widget>[
                        Container( margin : EdgeInsets.all(20), child:  Icon(Icons.calculate)),
                        Text ("Mathemathics")
                      ]
```

Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#27ce0
debugOwner: GestureDetector
state: ready
won arena
finalPosition: Offset(213.3, 415.7)
finalLocalPosition: Offset(197.3, 22.4)
button: 1
sent tap down

Comment: code looks perfect. There must be some other problem. Try using `RawMaterialButton` instead of `GestureDetector`.

Comment: nice to know it is working. I would appreciate if you can click the up arrow for my answer.